Stokes’ theorem on surface defined by $x^2+y^2=z^2+1$ and $F=(-yz^2, xz^2, 0)$
Question:

Let $H$ be the unbounded surface $x^2 + y^2 = z^2 +1$ and let $S$ be the subset of $H$ such that $1\le z \le \sqrt2$.
Calculate the vector area element $d\bf S$ in terms of $\rho$ and $\phi$ (using standard cylindrical polar coordinates) and use it to directly calculate
$$ \int_S\nabla \times \textbf{F} \cdot d\textbf{S}$$
where $\textbf{F} = (-yz^2, xz^2, 0)$ then use Stokes’ theorem to attain the same result.
What would the value be if instead $S’$ was the subset of $H$ with $-1 \le z \le \sqrt2$?

Edit my thoughts were completely wrong, so I’ve removed that attempt. I’m still struggling but here’s what I’ve got now
I think $d\textbf{S} = (\frac{\rho^2c}{\sqrt{\rho²-1}}, \frac{\rho^2s}{\sqrt{\rho^2-1}},-\rho)^T d\phi d\rho$ and that integral would be $\int^\sqrt3_\sqrt2 \int^{2\pi}_0 \nabla \times \textbf{A} \cdot d\textbf{S}$, doing this got me $8\pi$ which disagrees with the suggested answer of $44\pi$ given in a response

From the equation of the surface we know immediately that the surface normal should be parallel to $(x,y,-z)$, which $(0,0,\rho)$ is not. You have a triple integral later but a surface integral is a double integral. The problem is asking you to integrate in the polar parts of cylindrical coordinates only.

$44\pi$ is not the correct answer so you are on the right track. As a sanity check, we know that $$\mathbf{dS} = \left(\frac{x}{z},\frac{y}{z},-1\right)dxdy$$ and $$\nabla\times\mathbf{F} = (-2xz,-2xy,2z^2)$$ which leaves the dot product as $$(-2x^2-2y^2-2z^2)dxdy = (-2-4z^2)dxdy$$ From here it is much simpler to switch to polar coordinates normally rather than go through the entire cross product process just to arrive at the same answer. $$= (-2-4(\rho^2-1))\rho d\rho d\phi$$ which very neatly integrates to the correct answer.

@NinadMunshi that’s very similar to what I did, except I have an extra factor of $\rho$ in my $d\textbf{S}$ im not sure where I went wrong to get it.

Hint: you didn't do anything wrong and I didn't do anything wrong, both of our dS are correct. Pay really close attention to my process. How did I come up with my dS? (I didn't use a cross product)

@NinadMunshi I see how the vectors are the same direction, but what different step would need to be taken in the working to account for the difference in magnitude? (sorry if I’m missing something really obvious!)

It's a known formula. If your parametrization variables are $x$ and $y$ with $z=f(x,y)$ then we know that dS is automatically $$\mathbf{dS}=\pm\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x},\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}, -1\right)$$ and since we already know that the normal vector had to be parallel to the gradient of the surface, I simply divided the vector by $z$ to get the $-1$ in the third entry.

The reason why polar coordinates gives the extra factor is because $dxdy=\rho d\rho d\phi$

I can confirm that $8\pi$ is correct on the Stokes side. The suggested (now deleted) answer was mistaken because it incorrectly parameterized the circular boundaries and neglected to consider that they have opposite orientations.

Start with position vector $\vec r=\langle x,y,z\rangle.$ The position vector of the cone surface $x^2+y^2=z^2+1$, $z\in[1,\sqrt2]$ can be parametrized by polar coordinates as
$$\vec r=\langle r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta, \sqrt{r^2-1}\rangle$$
where $r\in[\sqrt2,\sqrt3]$, $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$. Then $d\vec S=(d\vec r_r\times d\vec r_\theta)drd\theta$
$$d\vec S=\langle -\frac{r^2\cos\theta}{\sqrt{r^2-1}},-\frac{r^2\sin\theta}{\sqrt{r^2-1}}, r\rangle drd\theta$$
The curl of the given vector field $\vec F=\langle-yz^2,-xz^2,0\rangle $ in polar coordinates
$$\vec\nabla\times\vec F=\langle -2r\cos\theta\sqrt{r^2-1}, -2r\sin\theta\sqrt{r^2-1}, 2(r^2-1)\rangle$$
and thus $\vec\nabla\times\vec F\cdot d\vec S=4r^3-2r$ givin the flux $\Phi=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_\sqrt2^\sqrt3(4r^3-2r)drd\theta=8\pi$.
...
Boundary integral
$$W=\int_C\vec F\cdot d\vec r$$ where $C=-C_1\cup C_2$,
$C_1: \vec r=\langle \sqrt2\cos\theta,\sqrt2\sin\theta,1\rangle$,
$C_2: \vec r=\langle \sqrt3\cos\theta,\sqrt3\sin\theta,\sqrt2\rangle$, $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$.
Then $$W=-4\pi+12\pi=8\pi.$$
Notice that $C_1$ is negatively oriented I guess since the normal vector of the surface is inward.
Hence $\Phi=W.$
